# Trouble with phpmailer and Email Spambox Filters

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer, contact-form

I am currently setup with a php form via Bootstrap 4, validating with Bootstrap validator and sending with phpmailer. I have the "from" field set to $_POST['inputEmail'] and it triggers the email filter when sent.

The form goes to an IT ticketing software that requires the "from" field in the email to be the client email.

I know it is best practice to have the "from" field something in the same domain as your server, but I was wondering if there is a safe way past this so I can make the "from" field whatever the client types in the form or their email address.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing *practically* preventing you from using the user-supplied address as the from address. It's not so much that it's "best practice", it's that your email will likely never be delivered if you forge the from address like that (at least if your mail server is any good at all). You may be able to configure your mail server to whitelist your submission form as a mail source that should be exempt from such checks, but that also means you're setting yourself up for abuse. This is really a bug in your ticketing software.

It would not surprise me if your ticketing software has some other way of creating requests from users, such as an HTTP API that you can call with appropriate params, including the identity of the user, without having to forge a from address. You're not alone in this; google calendar makes the same mistake, and it results in email bounces.

Comment: Thank you. I have been badgering my client to give me access to the developer portal of their software for this very reason. I guess this will be the solution until then. The ball is in their court.